# Python: Is there any rule can protect some words not to be processed in data preprocessing step

Tags: python, spell-checking, data-processing

I am a beginner and doing some data preprocessing work for textual data. There are some mistakes in there.
For example, the autospell step will make error corrections for some particular proper nouns.

```
from autocorrect import spell

def autospell(text):
    spells = [spell(w) for w in (nltk.word_tokenize(text))]
    return " ".join(spells)

def main():
    text = "skyrim"
    spell_text = autospell(text)
    print (spell_text)
```

Result: syria

Moreover, I also want to avoid removing numbers only for the word "E3".

```
def remove_numbers(text):
    output = ''.join(c for c in text if not c.isdigit())
    return output
def main():
    text = "in 2000, I am watching the E3"
    print (remove_numbers(text))
```

Result: in , I am watching the E

So, I'd like to ask that is there any rule for me to set to protect such words (proper nouns) avoid from being processed.

Comment: What you can do is store the words that do not require to be autocorrected into a hashset. Once you come across a word that is present in the ignore_hashset you can simply skip the autospell/remove_numbers part for it.